# Windows evented API to react on drive mounting?

Tags: c, winapi, events, filesystems

Does Windows provide some sort of evented API so I can run some code whenever a drive (say a usb stick) is attached?
Similar to how [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx) is for events on the filesystem?
I am not interested only in hardware changes, a user can also mount a volume, a ftp drive or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure of the API, but you can handle the [**WM_DEVICECHANGE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) message.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for WNetAddConnection2 API.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That seems to be for network questions, while the OP is asking about drive changes...